# "as much details as you can remember"

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

A: I don't remember much, though. 
B: Just try to give me as much details as you can remember.

I feel like something is wrong in B's sentence. I've never heard people say something like this.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The issue here is the use of **many** vs. **much**. Typically, **many** modifies countable nouns, while **much** modifies uncountable ones. [Reference](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/quantifiers/much-many-a-lot-of-lots-of-quantifiers)

With "details," a countable noun, the proper sentence would be: 
"Try to give me as many details as you can remember."

But you could also have "detail" used as an uncountable noun like "information":
"Try to give me as much detail as you can remember."

Answer (score 21):

It's the combination of *much* and *details* (plural) that doesn't work.

You should use one of the following:

> As much detail.
>   As many details.

*Detail*, as a mass noun, takes a singular form—which *much* is used with. (*As much water* or *as much candy*.) And *details*, as a countable noun, is plural—which *many* is used with (*as many drinks* or *as many chocolates*).